# What's a proper greeting to use when writing a formal e-mail to a university?

Tags: formality, email, letter-writing, greetings

I think the preferred option is to use "Dear Professor XYZ", but what should one use when the identity of the recipient is unknown?

Comment: When you say that the identity of the recipient is unknown, do you mean that you don't have an exact name?

Answer (score -1):

**"To whom it may concern,"** is a go-to for formal letters where the recipient is unknown or vague.